# Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**Update based on @Tom solution:**

SongsManager.java

```
public class SongsManager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>    {

          public interface SongsMasterCallback {         
        void showSongList(List<HashMap<String, String>> result);     
    } 

    private SongsMasterCallback  mCallback;      
    public SongsManager (SongsMasterCallback  callback) 
    {         
        mCallback = callback;    
    }   

    // Constructor
    //public SongsManager(){ }


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  doInBackground(Void... params) 
          {
             //populating all the data....
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             //.........
             songsList.add(map);
    }

       return songsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        mCallback.showSongList(result); 
    } 
}
```

main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity implements SongsMasterCallback {

public void showSongList(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) 
{
     this.songsList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) result;     
     // then do something with the list here 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  new SongsManager(this).execute();
  Log.d("songsSize", "string : "+songsList.size()); //it shows 0 ??? 

}

}
```

**end of update**

I am working on a class using AsyncTask and below is what i am getting when i try to execute

the error is on the design time so there is no LogCat

here is the class:

SongManager.java

```
public class SongsManager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {


// Constructor
public SongsManager(){ }


@Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Xml_Parser_Custom_Listview parser = new Xml_Parser_Custom_Listview();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_NAME);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            //adding the rows into to the map...

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        return songsList;
    }


}
```

main.java file

trying to execute the AsyncTask:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
songsList = new SongsManager().execute();
```

here is the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned from `SongsManager.execute()` is not the results of the computation; it's the `AsyncTask` itself. To publish your results, write a method in `SongsManager`:

```
void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {
    songsList = result; // or something similar
    // then update the UI to reflect the results
}
```

In this method, `songsList` is the variable to which you are now trying to assign the return value from `new SongsManager.execute()`. If this variable is not visible to the `SongsManager` class (e.g., it's not a nested class of your main class), then you'll have to arrange for a call-back:

```
public class SongsManager
    extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Map<String,String>>
{
    public interface SongsMasterCallback {
        void showSongList(List<Map<String, String>> result);
    }

    private SongsMasterCallback mCallback;

    public SongsMaster(SongsMasterCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Map<String, String>>  doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // as before
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, String>> result) {
        mCallback.showSongList(result);
    }
}
```

Then declare your activity to `implement SongsManager.SongsManagerCallback` and add is method:

```
void showSongList(List<Map<String, String>> songList) {
    this.songList = songList;
    // then do something with the list here
}
```

Comment: how would i call that in main.java file?  i tried to call like this `songsList1 = new SongsManager().execute();` but still get the same error message ... after implementing onPostExecute

Comment: @AbuHamzah The value returned from `execute()` is not the result of your background task; it is the task itself. Do not try to assign it to a variable of the result type. Your UI thread needs to proceed for the moment without the results. When the results are available, the task's `onPostExecute` will be called and you can update the UI at that point.

Comment: i understand but my UI is depend on the `songsList` variable so i am not sure how does the UI update the `songsLits`

Comment: @AbuHamzah I updated my answer with some code that shows how you can do this

Comment: i am not sure the above one will work because the SongManager is being called from multiple activity not just one so in this scenario how you will approach? what i see in the above code is that you are defining the hard-coded activity name... any thoughts?

Comment: @AbuHamzah - Define an interface that specifies the `showSongList` method. Declare each relevant activity to use that interface and change SongsMaster to accept an instance of the interface, rather than an instance of an activity.

Comment: @Tod: thanks and i have updated my question and please have a look when you get chance and its not working as expected the size of the songList is still 0.

Comment: @AbuHamzah - Is songsList empty just before doInBackground returns? If so, then that's a completely different problem that has nothing to do with AsyncTask and you should ask about it in a separate question.

Comment: @Tod: maybe the way i am calling the method is wrong, can you check the code that i have updated in my question just to make sure i am calling the right way? - thanks.

Comment: i have a new question continuation of this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702880/returning-data-from-asynctask-to-any-activity

Answer (score 0):

That's because you do not get the `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` returned when you create / execute the AsyncTask. You get it back on the onPostExecute().
You should create/execute the task like this

```
SongsManager songsList = new SongsManager().execute();
```

and then have a onPostExecute in your AsyncTask like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) 
{
  // do stuff with the ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result parameter.
}
```

Comment: yes i got it, but still get the same error message when i try to call from main.java file.. like how you showed.