# Using AsyncTasks as separate public classes 

Tags: android, android-asynctask

this question is a continuation of what i have asked orginally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690055/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-asynctask)

i am trying to find a better way to pass the ArrayList from `AsyncTask` to the `Activity` (any activity that calls the AsyncTask) so in my situation i have a `SongsManager.java` which extends to `AsyncTask` as you can see below.

my question is, It does not returning me the `songsList` i am getting size of 0... any idea what i am missing or do i need to tweak or add any code further?

SongsManager.java

```
 public class SongsManager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>    {

              public interface SongsMasterCallback {         
            void showSongList(List<HashMap<String, String>> result);     
        } 

        private SongsMasterCallback  mCallback;      
        public SongsManager (SongsMasterCallback  callback) 
        {         
            mCallback = callback;    
        }   

        // Constructor
        //public SongsManager(){ }


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  doInBackground(Void... params) 
              {
                 //populating all the data....
           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 //.........
                 songsList.add(map);
        }

           return songsList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            mCallback.showSongList(result); 
        } 
    }
```

main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity implements SongsMasterCallback {

public void showSongList(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) 
{
     this.songsList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) result;     
     // then do something with the list here 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  new SongsManager(this).execute();
  Log.d("songsSize", "string : "+songsList.size()); //it shows 0 ??? 

}

}
```

Comment: do you have values in List @ the time of returning songsList from doInbackgroung

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class SongsManager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>    {

            public interface SongsMasterCallback {         
            void showSongList(List<HashMap<String, String>> result);     
        } 

        private SongsMasterCallback  mCallback;      
        public SongsManager (SongsMasterCallback  callback) 
        {         
            mCallback = callback;    
        }   

        // Constructor
        //public SongsManager(){ }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  doInBackground(Void... params) 
              {
                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                 //populating all the data....
                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 //.........

                 return map;
               }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            songsList.add(result);
            mCallback.showSongList(result); 
        }
```

This is happening because you are creating object of songsList in UI thread and adding data in background thread.

Comment: how do i call from main.java class ?

Comment: You mean to say result in onPostExecute is coming with size 0. Correct?

Comment: i havent tried your code, let me do that and i will get back to you.

Comment: in the main.java file i have added this line of code to execute `new SongsManager(this).execute();` and i still get size 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8872/discussion-between-androdev-and-abu-hamzah)

Answer (score 0):

And if you pass the reference of the songsList  to the AsynTask?

```
public class SongsManager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>    {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList; 


    public SongsManager (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList) 
    {         
       this.songsList = songsList;    
    }   


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  doInBackground(Void... params) 
          {
             //populating all the data....
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             //.........
             songsList.add(map);
    }

       return songsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onPostExecute(result);

    } 
}
```

and in the main.java call 
`new SongsManager(songsList).execute();`

Comment: i have updated my code with the pattern you showed but i am still getting the size songsList 0

Comment: when i run my code it first goes to >>SongManager.java `(public SongsManager (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList)` then songsList size is 0 here then goes to the main.java and `new SongsManager(songsList).execute();` then goes to SongManager 'doInBackground` there i see the songsList size = 5 (which is correct) and when it comes back to main.java file then it the size of it is 0

Comment: Maybe if you create a static reference... Create an abstract Class and declare there "public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;" Then refer to this object with Class.songsList... dont forget to initialize. This way is not necessary to pass arguments to the asyncTask.